# Drupal 7 Picture Module PHP Output

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7

I am updating my Drupal 7 site to use the picture module (https://www.drupal.org/project/picture) and have a number of php template overrides currently using image style URL to print the image url.

```
print image_style_url($image_style, $img_url);
```

How can I print the picture formatted image via PHP? I've come up with the code below and it is close, I am sending incorrect data for the breakpoints variable.

```
$variables = array(
    'width' => 1570,
    'height' => 950,
    'breakpoints' => array("breakpoints.theme.basic2.large"),
    'uri' => 'public://dev_images/map.jpg',
    'style_name' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_large_1x');
print theme('picture',$variables);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for picture module 2.x. I worked it out myself and came up with the following solution. This would be an example if each breakpoint is using a style, and you include 1x and 2x for each style.

```
$variables = array(
    'width' => 1570,
    'height' => 950,
    'breakpoints' => array(
             'breakpoints.theme.basic2.large' => array(
               '1x' => array(
                 'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
                 'image_style' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_medium_1x'
                ),
               '2x' => array(
                  'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
                  'image_style' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_medium_1x'  
               ),
             ),
             'breakpoints.theme.basic2.medium' => array(
               '1x' => array(
                 'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
                 'image_style' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_medium_1x'
                ),
               '2x' => array(
                  'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
                  'image_style' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_medium_1x'  
               ),
             ),
             'breakpoints.theme.basic2.smalltablet' => array(
               '1x' => array(
                 'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
                 'image_style' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_medium_1x'
                ),
               '2x' => array(
                  'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
                  'image_style' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_medium_1x'  
               ),
             ),
             'breakpoints.theme.basic2.small' => array(
               '1x' => array(
                 'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
                 'image_style' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_medium_1x'
                ),
               '2x' => array(
                  'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
                  'image_style' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_medium_1x'  
               ),
             ),


       ),
    'uri' => 'public://dev_images/map.jpg',
    'style_name' => 'blog_list_breakpoints_theme_basic2_large_1x'



);
  print theme('picture',$variables);
```

The theme picture function requires the uri, style name (for the fallback image style), and an array of breakpoints. The image widths and heights appear to be optional. The breakpoints array should be formatted like this

```
array(
 breakpoint_name => array(
   multiplier => array(
     mapping_type => _none|sizes|image_style,
     image_style => image_style_name,
     sizes => '(min-width: 700px) 700px, 100vw',
     sizes_image_styles => array(
       thumbnail => thumbnail,
       medium => medium,
       large => large,
     ),
   ),
 ),


  );
```

You can see how this was applied in my full variables variable. I removed the sizes arrays from my code since I am using image styles for each breakpoint.

Comment: This means you have to re-declare all the breakpoints? Can't you just use the values of the breakpoints group defined in the theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your breakpoints and call theme_picture like this:

```
$breakpoints = picture_get_mapping_breakpoints(picture_mapping_load('megamenu_thumbnails'));

$picture = theme_picture(array(
  'uri' => 'public://dev_images/map.jpg',
  'breakpoints' => $breakpoints,
  'style_name' => 'rectangular_210_170_breakpoints_theme_ab_large_1x',
  'timestamp'   => NULL,
));

print $picture;
```

In this example, `megamenu_thumbnails` is the Picture Mapping name, and `rectangular_210_170_breakpoints_theme_ab_large_1x` is a fallback image style.

This works for me using Picture version 7.x-2.13.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me with Picture 7.x-2.13:

```
$breakpoints = picture_get_mapping_breakpoints(picture_mapping_load('PICTURE_MAPPING'));
// Always use theme(), in case a module or theme as overridden the default theme_picture()
$picture = theme('picture', array(
    'uri'                   => 'IMAGE_URI',
    'breakpoints'           => $breakpoints,
    // Optional stuff
    'lazyload'              => true,
    'lazyload_aspect_ratio' => true,
    // You can also include 'style_name' here if you don't want automatic fallback
));
```

Replace `PICTURE_MAPPING` and `IMAGE_URI` with the appropriate strings.